# Error "unexpected token List"

Tags: apex

I am getting error "unexpected token List " while compiling the following code

```
trigger Lead_Casecloseafter on Lead (after update) {
    // Collect ODST leads
    id vRecordTypeId = [select Id from RecordType where name='ODST_Leads'];
    set<id> vSetCaseId= new set<id>();

    for (Lead vLead:trigger.new)
    {
        if (vLead.RecordTypeId == vRecordTypeId && vLead.IsConverted == true)
            vSetCaseId.add (vLead.ODST_Case__c);
        }
    }

    // Looking up associated Case
    List <Case> vLstcase = new List ([select id,name,Case_Number__c,Status from            ODST_Case__c where ID IN:vSetCaseId]);

    for (Case vCase:vLstcase)
    {   
        vCase.Status == 'Closed';

        if(!vLstcase.isempty())
            update vLstcase; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the rest of the code, it looks like you're missing an opening brace (`{`) after this line:

```
if (vLead.RecordTypeId == vRecordTypeId && vLead.IsConverted == true)
```

The closing brace immediately after the `if` closes the function (since there was no block opened for the `if`), causing the `List` line to be in an invalid context.

Comment: In the above code line List<Case> vLstcase = [select id,name,Case_Number__c,Status from Case__c where ID IN:vSetCaseId];I am trying to reference Sobject Case by using the lookup filed ODST_Case__c. So how should I write that?